# Video.mp4 not found after updating to latest Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I've an application that has a video which is running in the background (Like a background video). But after updating to the latest Xcode I'm getting an error:

> Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I'm getting this error after removing the .mp4 file from Xcode and re-added it. Earlier I got an error like

> Could not find videoName.mp4 on desktop

The video is placed exactly where it used to be and everything worked just fine till now. The video is located inside Xcode under the folder.

```
    private func setupView()
{
    let path = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mydogwalkvideo", ofType: ".mp4")!)

    let player = AVPlayer(url: path)

    let newLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    newLayer.frame = self.videoView.frame
    self.videoView.layer.addSublayer(newLayer)
    newLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

    player.play()
    player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayer.ActionAtItemEnd.none


    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.videoDidPlayToEnd(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification"), object: player.currentItem)

}
```

What could possibly gone wrong when I updated to the latest Xcode version? And how comes this error appears? I've a video and I've not changed anything in the code and it worked just fine for months.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the file is actually included in the project with the target membership.
For example:

[image]

Hope it helps

Comment: I managed it fix it yesterday. The reason was exactly like this, thanks for your input. I'll accept this.